# How to send verification email when subscribe the newsletter in nopcommerce 3.70

Tags: email, nopcommerce

I want to send verification email when user subscribe the newsletter in nopcommerce 3.70.

for sending verification mail is there any admin panel configuration or want to change any code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

NopCommerce gives a configuration of it at Admin > settings > Email Accounts

You can add configuration details over there.
Here is [link](http://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/Admin/EmailAccount/Create) of Admin store demo.

Make sure `NewsLetterSubscription.ActivationMessage` is active.